# int.Parse not working

Tags: c#, parsing

```
static void Main()
{        
    Console.Write("Please input a number: ");
    Console.WriteLine("\n The number you selected was {0} \n", method());
}

static int method()
{
    int var = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return var;
}
```

The above code throws a format exception. I tried storing the input in a string variable and then parsing, but it had the same problem. I also tried using the `Convert` class and still had the same problem. I would appreciate if someone could show me where I am wrong.

I am trying to convert 23.4, for example. (It works for Natural numbers but why not 4345.5, for example)

Comment: What have you entered into the console?

Comment: Is 23.4 an integer?

Comment: Forgive me i forgot to put what input is not working:( UPDATED now.

Comment: Isnt Parse supposed to make it?

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis No, it's supposed to parse an integer.  You don't have an integer, so it can't be parsed as one.

Comment: Because int.Parse() will parse an integer number, if you write 4345.5 it'll throw an exception because it's not integer. Use float.Parse() or (better) int.TryParse/float.TryParse

Comment: Then shouldn't Convert.ToInt32() do the job the cuase it still produces the same error

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis It gives the same error for the same reason.  You don't have an integer, and you're asking for one.

Comment: Ok then probably i am really not understanding something here. If Convert.ToInt32(string value) doenst work how i am i supposed to convert a an input of  23.4 to an int ? (e.g. take 23 as a result)

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis see my answer. You still need the `float` part but you can return only the integer part. 3.6 becomes 3, for example.

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis: you can use the code you've accepted to get the double. Then use `(int)number` to get an integer where the decimal part is simply truncated. If you want that it gets rounded use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

Comment: Just as a side note - I'd avoid naming a variable `var` (`int var = ...`) - it is a reserved word in C# used for inferred types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). It works just okay though without errors. Interesting thing that you can do even more with double var -  `var var = int.Parse("123");` but again, I'd avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`23.4` is not an integer, so you cannot use `int.Parse` (or `int.TryParse`). Instead you have to parse it to a decimal number like `decimal` or `double`. You can use the `TryParse` methods like [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent an exception if it's not a valid number:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
double number;
if(double.TryParse(input.Trim(), out number))
{
    // valid number
    Console.WriteLine("\n The number you selected was {0} \n", number);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a real number.");
}
```

**Update** from your comments i can see that you want to display an integer.

You can use `(int)number` to get an integer where the decimal part is simply truncated. If you want that it gets rounded use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

```
int integer = (int) number; // decimal part is truncated
integer = (int) Math.Round(number, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // rounded to two digits
```

If you just want to display a string without the decimal part you can also use [format strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string numberString = number.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `double` or `float` for rational numbers:

```
float num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the integer part of your input string (3.6 becomes 3, for example) like this:

```
static int method()
{
    float var = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return (int)Math.Floor(var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer32.Parse` is for parsing 32 bit integers.  It cannot parse numbers that cannot be represented as a 32 bit integer, such as 23.4, and it will throw an exception when it cannot parse the data.  Use a different numeric representation if you wish to represent non-integer numbers.